# Accessing database using only one user id and password

Tags: c++

Can we get the file from database using only one login from multiple users?

Let me explain to you suppose I have one database and only one log-id and password for database.
I want to use this database for multiple users across the globe each and every user ask for different files (while user doesn't have this database id and password) at the same time with this login id and password.

I want to create new layer between the database and the user to get these files.
Is this possible or I can say feasible and what are the pros and cons?

Comment: Which database are you referring to? How do your clients access that database? Does it store sensitive information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally database or data source access is encapsulated in [Data Access Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) that resides a [Data Access Layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_layer). In Java this can be done using JDBC API or Object-Relational Mapping framework such as Hibernate or iBatis. Since this questions is tagged with c++, [ODB(C++)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ODB_(C%2B%2B)) is an option.